# How to Reduce the expression

Tags: c, syntax, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

How to reduce the expression? If I am right, x assign 0 if only x = 0; otherwise x assign 1. However, How can it do shorten?

```
 x = (x = 0) ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: It's my one of the hometasks

Comment: just `x = 1;`......

Comment: @usr That text is what OP's _assumption_, not the requirement, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping aside all the *assumption* part, first let me state this clearly, there is **no undefined behaviour here**.

Quoting `C11`, chapter  §6.5.15, *Conditional operator* (*emphasis mine*)

> **The first operand is evaluated; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and the
>   evaluation of the second or third operand (whichever is evaluated).** The second operand
>   is evaluated only if the first compares unequal to 0; the third operand is evaluated only if
>   the first compares equal to 0; the result is the value of the second or third operand
>   (whichever is evaluated), [....]

and then, the result is assigned to the LHS of the outer assignment operator.

the statement,

```
x = (x = 0) ? 0 : 1;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = 1;
```

as `x= 0` finally evaluates to FALSE ***unconditionally***.

Related, quoting the standard, chapter §6.5.16, *Assignment operators*, (*emphasis mine*)

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. **An
>   assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment,**

---

Note:

that said, related to the *understanding* mentioned in the question

> *x assign 0 if only x = 0; otherwise x assign 1*

is wrong. There is no *if..else..then* category condition check present in the given statement.

Comment: Try to compile under GCC with warnings, it will say `warning: operation on ‘x’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]` ...

Comment: @iharob well, that's interesting. I would like to get more info on that. Where exactly am I reading the standard wrong? (I hope you would not mind re-wording the comment, right?)

Comment: @molbdnilo Sir, i'm not very sure I'm following you there, I still fail to see how the final assignment is causing the problem. As we can see, the first operand of the conditional is evaluated first (`x` is assigned), after that , **there is a sequence point** and after that, evaluation of the third operand and then, the result is obtained, which is again assigned to the same variable `x`. So, how the intermediate sequence point is not considerable here? Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that you meant `x == 0`, this is pretty short:

```
x = !!x;
```

Explanation:

If `x` is `0`, `!x` is `1`, so `!!x` is `0`.
If `x` is not `0`, `!x` is `0`, so `!!x` is `1`.

If `x = 0` is intentional, the code is undefined.

But you can make a shorter version that is well-defined and which I believe captures the writer's intention:

```
 x = 1;
```

since the value of `x = 0` is `0`.

Comment: The most interesting thing is that x = 0, only with one equals sign

Comment: Yep! I saw your answer, please, explain it!

Comment: `x = 0` evaluates to be false so the value beside `:` is assigned to `x`

Comment: @molbdnilo `If x = 0 is intentional, the code is undefined.` you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 0):

If it is exactly the one you posted then it is undefined behavior.

The expression

```
x = (x = 0);
```

is undefined because `x = 0` modifies `x` before assigning it to `x` so it's said that there is no sequence point between the two sub expressions. You can read about [sequence point](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sequence-points-in-c-set-1/) here.

It is equivalent to

```
x = x++;
```

which many programmers would immediately identify as undefined behavior, even though it's harder to see it in `x = (x = 0)` it's the same problem, there are side effects arising from `x = 0` so the behavior is not defined in this case.

Comment: Ummm.. not sure if i'm missing something, but why it's UB?

Comment: To be more specific, there is a Seq point between 1st and 2nd/3rd operand, right?

Comment: @iharob I still did not get the case, there is a sequence point, right?